# Icon list import

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, font-awesome, antd

After googleing for a while among different libraries, I couldn find what I am looking for at the moment, I Am using antd library, I would need to give the user the posibility to search an icon according to the name of it, something similar as all the major icon libraries out there have to search for icons, the question is if there is any library giving the option to query their api to get the list of icons available.

expected result should be sht like it:
[enter link description here](https://ant.design/components/icon/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, I have come across these libraries which give HTTP JSON API and allows you to programmatically access resources on the service, such as icons, icon sets, categories, styles, authors, etc.

- iconfinder Link: https://developer.iconfinder.com/reference/overview-1
- svgapi Link: https://svgapi.com/

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! @Amir Achhodi